# Codeigniter image upload with text field validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

In Codeigniter I have `add_main_products` function to upload image to the database and before that I want to validate a text field something like `<input type="text" name="product_name">`
. How do I do that inside the `add_main_products()` function

```
   function add_main_products(){

        $config['upload_path'] = 'application/views/uploads/';            
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';      
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);    

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {

            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('admin/admin_add_mainproduct', $error);

        } else {

            $this->mod_products->add_main_product($this->upload->data());
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $this->load->view('admin/admin_add_mainproduct', $data);  }    

    }
```

Comment: why don't you used <input type="file" name="product_name"> in your codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
     function add_main_products(){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_name', 'Product Name', 'required');    

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $this->load->view('admin/admin_add_mainproduct');
        }
           else{

             $config['upload_path'] = 'application/views/uploads/';            
             $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';            
             $this->load->library('upload', $config);

             if (! $this->upload->do_upload()){
                $error['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                $this->load->view('admin/admin_add_mainproduct', $error);
                return FALSE;
                }

               $this->mod_products->add_main_product($this->upload->data());
               $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
               $this->load->view('admin/admin_add_mainproduct', $data);
         }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this ...

```
function add_main_products()
{
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_name', $this->lang->line('product_add_name'), 'required|xss_clean');

   if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) 
   {
     // Put your upload code
   }
}
```

and load a this `$this->load->library('form_validation');` library  in `_construct function`